# Silverlight Image Panning

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am working on silverlight application and I want to panning image like top, bottom, left, right how I can panning the image.

I had use the pixel shadering but I am not success of this.

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You could also look at the Blend behavior for dragging.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. User can preview an enlarged image using this window, and pan the image to the sections that is more relevant, e.g. the bottom part of the image.

To use the window:

```
BitmapImage BMP = /* resolve the bitmap */;

PreviewImageWindow.Execute(BMP);
```

The code (behind) for the window is shown below.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ITIS.Controls.LinearViewer.Windows {

public partial class PreviewImageWindow : ChildWindow {

    /// <summary>See Execute</summary>
    PreviewImageWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }

    static public void Execute(BitmapImage imageSource) {

        PreviewImageWindow Window = new PreviewImageWindow();

        Window.Image.Source = imageSource;

        /* don't allow the window to grow larger than the image */
        Window.MaxWidth = imageSource.PixelWidth;
        Window.MaxHeight = imageSource.PixelHeight;

        Window.Show();
    }

    private void ChildWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

        if (e.Key == Key.Escape) {

            DialogResult = false;
        }
    }

    Point? _lastPoint;

    bool _isMouseDown;

    private void image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

        ((Image)sender).CaptureMouse();

        _isMouseDown = true;

        ShowCursor(e.GetPosition(Canvas));

        _lastPoint = e.GetPosition((Image)sender);
    }

    private void image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

        ((Image)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();

        _isMouseDown = false;

        ShowCursor(e.GetPosition(Canvas));

        _lastPoint = null;
    }

    private void image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {

        if (_lastPoint != null) {

            Image Image = (Image)sender;

            Point CurrentPoint = e.GetPosition(Image);

            double 
                XDelta = CurrentPoint.X - _lastPoint.Value.X,
                YDelta = CurrentPoint.Y - _lastPoint.Value.Y;

            _lastPoint = null;

            if (XDelta != 0) {
                double NewLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(Image) + XDelta;
                if (NewLeft <= 0 && NewLeft + Image.ActualWidth >= Canvas.ActualWidth) {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(Image, NewLeft);
                }
            }

            if (YDelta != 0) {
                double NewTop = Canvas.GetTop(Image) + YDelta;
                if (NewTop <= 0 && NewTop + Image.ActualHeight >= Canvas.ActualHeight) {
                    Canvas.SetTop(Image, NewTop);
                }
            }

            _lastPoint = e.GetPosition(Image);
        }

        Point CanvasPoint = e.GetPosition(Canvas);
        ShowCursor(CanvasPoint);
    }

    private void Canvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        TryDefaultImageToTop();
    }

    void TryDefaultImageToTop() {

        if (Image == null || Canvas == null) { return; }

        /* move the image up so we can focus on the road? user-friendly since we are most-likely going to look at the road, not the horizon or top - half */
        if (!_initialized) {

            _initialized = true;

            Canvas.SetTop(Image, Canvas.ActualHeight - Image.ActualHeight);
            Canvas.SetLeft(Image, (Canvas.ActualWidth - Image.ActualWidth) / 2);
        }
    }

    bool _initialized;

    private void image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        TryDefaultImageToTop();
    }

    private void image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {

        imgOpenHand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        imgClosedHand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        ShowCursor(e.GetPosition(Canvas));
    }

    void ShowCursor(Point point) {

        if (_isMouseDown) {
            imgClosedHand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            imgOpenHand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            Canvas.SetLeft(imgClosedHand, point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(imgClosedHand, point.Y);
        }
        else {
            imgClosedHand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            imgOpenHand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Canvas.SetLeft(imgOpenHand, point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(imgOpenHand, point.Y);
        }
    }

    private void image_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        imgOpenHand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        imgClosedHand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

}

The XAML for the window is shown below:

```
<controls:ChildWindow 
x:Class="ITIS.Controls.LinearViewer.Windows.PreviewImageWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
Background="#383838" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"    
Title="Preview" Margin="50"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
KeyDown="ChildWindow_KeyDown"    
>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0" Cursor="None" IsHitTestVisible="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Cursor="None" IsHitTestVisible="True" x:Name="Canvas" Loaded="Canvas_Loaded">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" x:Name="Image"
               Cursor="None" Loaded="image_Loaded"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
               MouseLeftButtonUp="image_MouseLeftButtonUp"
               MouseMove="image_MouseMove"
               MouseEnter="image_MouseEnter"
               MouseLeave="image_MouseLeave"
               IsHitTestVisible="True"
               />
        <Image Style="{StaticResource HandOpenImage}" x:Name="imgOpenHand" 
               Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
               />
        <Image Style="{StaticResource HandClosedImage}" x:Name="imgClosedHand"
               Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
               />
    </Canvas>        
</Grid>
```

A few CATCHES / COMMENTS about this code:

1. The namespace for this window is "ITIS.Controls.LinearViewer.Windows", please change the namespace to something more relevant in your system.
2. The normal cursor image is [image: OpenHand] and when the mouse button is down, the image changes to [image: HandClosed]
3. The styles for the images, which I have in a global application wide resource dictionary:

(OPEN image style)

```
<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="HandOpenImage">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ITIS.Controls.LinearViewer.Silverlight;component/Images/HandOpen.png" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
</Style>
```

(CLOSED image style)

```
<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="HandClosedImage">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ITIS.Controls.LinearViewer.Silverlight;component/Images/HandClosed.png" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="11" />
</Style>
```

4. This preview tries to START with focus on the bottom half of the image, NOT the top half.

Hope this helps. It took me a while to iron out a few irritations.